my node is crashing after 20 minutes, what do i have to look for?
hello i changed my bitcoin node from a brix pc to a full desktop pc, formatted and installed ubuntu 22.04 downloaded the bitcoin core from snap store and now it crashes everytime after 15-20 mins, did the same installation steps as the old brix pc.
So what do i have to look for errors, processes??
(New specs, i7 10th gen, 16gb ram, 240ssd os, 2tb hdd for storage)

Have you checked the debug.log file in your Bitcoin directory?
